# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0>=0

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
**modelfit -inputfile dwi.Bfloat -schemefile 4Ddwi_b1000_bvector.scheme -model ldt -bgmask    brain_mask.nii.gz\ -outputfile dt.Bdouble**
```

but I get this error message up:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at imaging.DW_Scheme.readScheme(DW_Scheme.java:530)
at tools.CL_Initializer.initImagingScheme(CL_Initializer.java:1574)
at apps.ModelFit.initOptions(ModelFit.java:60)
at apps.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:24)
at apps.ModelFit.<init>(ModelFit.java:49)
at apps.EntryPoint.getExecutable(EntryPoint.java:142)
at apps.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:282)**
```

I'm fairly new to using commands like this to run programs and alter data, so any simple advice would be really helpful and appreciated!  I'm using commands from software called Camino, a diffusion brain imaging analysis software package developed by university college london, if that helps.

Comment: Can you post the syntax of the command? Which parameters does it expect?

Comment: Can you please submit the core where you try to run the command?

Comment: I suggest that, The question should be displayed in first hand so as to grab the attention of the people who wants to answer it.